# Where does Leia, Princess of Alderaan take place in relation to Star Wars Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, princess-leia

The book *Leia, Princess of Alderaan* begins when Princess Leia Organa turns sixteen years old. It seems to take place over a matter of months, or a year even. Leia is around sixteen when we see her in the *Star Wars Rebels* episode "A Princess on Lothal." How far away are the events of the book from the events of that episode. There wasn't even a passing reference to it in the book.

Comment: Just a small piece of advice, all of our major universes have universe tags, to ensure that everything from that universe is nicely logged away into that tag we add it to all questions in that universe, for example [star-wars], [star-trek], [star-gate] and [tolkiens-legendarium], etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book seems to choose to remain separate from the show series. However from the events of the book we can figure out that it must *certainly* have occurred before the events of [*A Princess on Lothal*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Princess_on_Lothal). This is because in the book Leia only begins to learn of the Rebellion and receives hints of it, however in the episode she's is clearly an included member, and sent by her father to help Phoenix Squadron.

According to [this timeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:SH:Timeline_of_Star_Wars_Rebels_Events) in the forum for the Star Wars wiki, it suggests that [*The Future of the Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Future_of_the_Force) and [*Legacy*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_(episode)) take place shortly before the events of *A Princess on Lothal*, we can presume that *Leia, Princess of Alderaan* takes place during the events of the preceding episodes, possibly up to *A Day's Duty*. This would mean that the novel ties in about half way into the second season of Star Wars rebels, during the events of *The Future of the Force* and *Legacy*.